# IQueryable in DynamicData project

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-data

I'm working with Dynamic Data Project, and I'm trying to execute query on IQueryable object.
I want to perform a query which checks if a text is contained in "SubjectID" field of my entity.

Here is my filter class:

```
public partial class SubjectIDFilter : System.Web.DynamicData.QueryableFilterUserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public override System.Linq.IQueryable GetQueryable(System.Linq.IQueryable source)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBox.Text))
            {
                return source;
            }

            return source;
        }

        protected void btnSearch_Click(Object sender,
                           EventArgs e)
        {
            OnFilterChanged();
        }

        public override Control FilterControl
        {
            get
            {
                return this.textBox;
            }
        }
    }
```

The code should be placed in "GetQueryable" method.

I've tried to write "source.Where ..." but the IDE intellisence doesn't recognize those LINQ methods ("Select, Where.." ) on my source object.
I didn't figure out how to write a query using "Expression" object (for CreateQuery method).

How can I perform a simple SQL query on that object ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create expression and return it using [IQueryProvider.CreateQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549139%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Below is the code to do what you want:

```
public override IQueryable GetQueryable(IQueryable source)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
    {
        return source;
    }

    string filterValue = textBox.Text;
    ConstantExpression value = Expression.Constant(filterValue);

    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType);
    MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, Column.Name);
    if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.Type) != null)
    {
        property = Expression.Property(property, "Value");
    }

    Expression comparison = Expression.Call(property, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new [] { typeof(string) }), value);
    LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(comparison, parameter);

    MethodCallExpression where = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable),
        "Where",
        new[] { source.ElementType },
        source.Expression,
        lambda);

    return source.Provider.CreateQuery(where);
}
```

This code is taken from Oleg's Sych [Understanding ASP.NET Dynamic Data: Filter Templates](http://www.olegsych.com/2010/07/understanding-aspnet-dynamic-data-filter-templates/) blog post. It gives a good insight of what is going on under the hood of dynamic data filtering mechanism and I highly recommend it for you to read.